# Execute task after another. doFirst, doLast Groovy/Gradle

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I'm new in gradle. How can I run exec one task after another? I've got a problem that task test1 runs before android.applicationVariants.all, and property test is empty,how to change it?

project A

```
String test = ''
android {
android.applicationVariants.all.doFirst { 
test = 'vasya' 
    }
task test1.doLast{
        println "$test"
}
```

But I've got the following output:

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/build.gradle' line: 57
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ProjectA'.
> No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.doFirst() is applicable for argument types: (build_6g09fl113rl613     iaq870b0hod0$_run_closure1_closure12_closure18) values: [build_6g09fl113rl613iaq870b0hod0$_run_closure1_closure12_closure18@5f81a4ab] 
Possible solutions: first(), toList(), asList(), sort(), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), sort(boolean)
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Use dependsOn to handle hierarchy:

```
task helloTask1 << {
 println "hello task 1"
}

task helloTask2(dependsOn: helloTask1) {
 println "hello task 2"
}
```

then, calling helloTask2 execustion will trigger helloTask1 first

2) Use mustRunAfter() if needed (this method is in incubating mode):

```
task helloTask1 {
 println "hello task 1"
}

task helloTask2 {
 mustRunAfter helloTask1
 println "hello task 2"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given two tasks defined:

```
task mainTask {
  println "main"
}

task nextTask {
  println "next task"
}
```

the following code

```
mainTask << {
  nextTask.execute()
}
```

executes `nextTask` after `mainTask` is run:

```
> gradle mainTask
main
next task
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [task's](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) mustRunAfter method.